# ActiveAdmin errors not showing up in New Relic. Rest of the site's errors show up just fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, newrelic

So the title explains it pretty succinctly. We use New Relic to look at the errors for our Rails 4 application. It works perfectly for the vast majority of the site. But for some reason any errors that occur on the ActiveAdmin portion of the site do not appear. This is a big issue since production doesn't show errors on the page, but we're having a hard time debugging without them. Does anyone have any experience with ActiveAdmin and New Relic?

Answer (score 0):

If an error is handled or does not propagate up the stack, New Relic will not see it. You can potentially use the New Relic notice_error method (details at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/newrelic/rpm/NewRelic/Agent:notice_error) to insure any handled errors are passed to New Relic.